# node request ISO-8859-1 not working since node 4

Tags: node.js, encoding, request, iso-8859-1

Im get a webpage with return latin1
[image: screenshot from browser (response from the website)]

it worked with iconv-lite for node 0.10. But now with

```
$ node -v
v4.1.1
```

[I can't use iconv-lite with the latest node version](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Node-v4-compatibility). So I tried to get back to Iconv:

```
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
...
  request(url, {
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET'}, function (err, resp, body) {
        var ic = new Iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8');
        var buf = ic.convert(body);
        body = buf.toString('utf-8');
```

But this results in `ï¿½ber`where it should be `Über`.

I've no idea how to solve this. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I think you could reuse the Iconv instance instead of creating it for every request over and over again.

Comment: In the [doc](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) it's always `UTF-8` (vs `utf-8` you used). Have you checked that?

Comment: 1. of course, this is only the test setup, 2. changed to UTF-8 but same issue

Comment: please try this: `var buf = ic.convert(Buffer(body,'binary'));`

Comment: hey @ɦassansin this results in 'ýber' instead of Über

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `latin1` instead of `iso-8859-1`. that's what the documentation says to use to convert from `iso-8859-1` to `utf-8`...

EDIT: you also have to set the request encoding to 'binary' for it to work.

EDIT 2: just realized, you won't even need Iconv when requesting in binary.

```
request(url, {... encoding: 'binary' ...},...
console.log(body)
```

Comment: this results in `ýberland`

Comment: i created a simple testcase,and found a solution. I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you! I can affirm that it's workin even without iconv (and its about 30% faster)!

Comment: Thank you man, Finally fixed my same problem after trying different methods for hours